# how to return value of nested function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a function in project

```
function findParentID(parentName) {
  Category.findOne({ categoryName: parentName }, function (err, foundParent) {
    var parentID = foundParent.categoryID;
    return parentID;
  });
}
module.exports.findParentID = findParentID;
```

and when I try to call this function, I am getting `undefined` in `console.log()`
This is how I am trying to call it

```
var parentName = req.body.parent_name;
var parentID = findParentID(parentName);
console.log(parentID);
```

based on my understanding, the function is not returning any value. How do I return a value from the function?

Comment: you need to return a value: `return Category.findOne(/* ... */ )`. Note that you're likely getting a promise from that.

Comment: @VLAZ i am completely new to programming. would you mind simplifying this a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code,you were trying to directly call the function which has db(async) operation.

Either use promises/async await.Once the value is returned accordingly do the consecutive operations

```js
function findParentID(parentName) {
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  Category.findOne({ categoryName: parentName }, function (err, foundParent) {
    var parentID = foundParent.categoryID;
    resolve(parentID);
  });
});

}
module.exports.findParentID = findParentID;


var parentName = req.body.parent_name;
   findParentID(parentName).then((parentID)=>{
   console.log(parentID);
  
  });
```

Update(As per recommendation)

```js
  var parentName = req.body.parent_name;
    Category.findOne({ categoryName: parentName }).then(foundParent => {
   
     var parentID = foundParent.categoryID;
      console.log(parentID);
    })
```

Comment: [There is no reason to use the Promise constructor here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: .findOne is already returning a promise.

Comment: If I have store returned `parentID` in a variable, how do I do that? while I am trying to store in a var, I am getting [object-promise] as result

Comment: @MridushyamalBarman try the following code 
 Category.findOne({ categoryName: parentName }).then(foundParent => {
 var parentID = foundParent.categoryID;
console.log(parentID)
})